# How do I get SQLite to cache results of a select command

Tags: sqlite, caching, query-optimization

I am running a web application with a backend SQLite database that solely performs read operations. Users connect to the database, search for entries via a select command, and view the results in a browser. But, the select is quite time-consuming because it involves character pattern matching across several million table rows. (The size of the results table is quite small).

Different users will generally do the *exact same* search, so if I can cache the results of the select the first time, the next user to search to database (concurrently or more likely a few days later) can get back the results quickly.

How can I do this in SQLite? Is there a pragma I need to use? I hear that SQLite has an automatic caching feature, but this does not seem to help. Note that I'm using a hosting service, so I cannot rebuild SQLite in anyway.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting the above question, I found one simple solution that seems effective that doesn't require any changes to the CPanel hosting service that I use.

Instead of caching the SQL results, I simple cache the entire webpage generated by the PHP script. Users making the exact same search are then given the cached page, bypassing the database completely.

I got the basic idea [here](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/caching-output-in-php/).

The advantage is that a quite complex results set involving several different database calls can all be cached in a very minimal space. Then, using PHP it's a trivial task to delete the cached webpages after a certain time.

I hope this helps others working on similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Are the users using different connections to the SQLite DB? Try using the PRAGMA command to increase cache size.

```
PRAGMA cache_size; 
PRAGMA cache_size = Number-of-pages;
```

> Query or change the suggested maximum
>   number of database disk pages that
>   SQLite will hold in memory at once per
>   open database file.

From documentation: http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size

Comment: Yes, the users are using different connections. Each time they make a search, a php script runs, which connects them to the database, gets them the results, and then terminates the connection. Would cache_size help in this case? Isn't this just for concurrent connections?

Comment: `PRAGMA cache_size;` gives me `-2000` back. How come that this is a negative value?

Answer (score 1):

I would use an external caching solution like

memcached

or

APC/Zend Cache (on PHP)

Then you have much more control over your cache (what to store, lifetimes, clearing the cache completely...)

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar issue which I attempted to optimise by hashing queries, and storing the hash/result in a CACHE table.
But there are gotchas - for example, the commands:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (col1 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000) AND (col2='StackOverflow');
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE (col2='StackOverflow') AND (col1 BETWEEN 1000 AND 2000);
```

Should give exactly the same answer, but MD5'ing those two string will give different results. Same goes for:

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM myTable;
SELECT col2,col1 FROM myTable;
```

If you can standardise how the queries come into the database (sorting SELECTables, WHERE filters, grouping, etc - all in our PHP/JavaScript), then you can reliably quick-hash the queries, do them, then store the result in your database. I would recommend storing it as JSON if your not going to return whole pages like the OP, because that saves having to convert it later, and JSON is pretty much always gzipped before sending it to the user (if your AJAXing to the users screen).

To really speed this up, your CACHE table should have the Hash column include the UNIQUE type so it is automatically indexed.

If you are using Node.js, then id go one step further and say you can read this CACHE table from disk on startup, store all the hashes in a set object, then when your server gets a query just do allHashes.has(hashedSortedQuery). Since that operation happens in memory, it is essentially instantaneous. If true, SELECT result from CACHE where Hash='hashedSortedQuery', else, (actual query).

One final note - from my experience doing the same thing, updating my SQLite version had a HUGE improvement on speed, and i only mention it because often on shared hosting servers, the latest version isn't always installed.  Heres a comparison i did today between the global SQLite version installed on my server, and the latest SQLite version compiled from source: http://pastebin.com/hpWu3UCk